# Any idea about keeping data locally with ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using `ionic framework` for my mobile app and I would like to make some `functions` like when `user` requests `data (json)` from `database` (using `REST API`) and it will keep on `local storage` on the device. whenever the user come back, `application` will use the data from `local storage` instead.

I read there are many options to do this (`$localstorage`, `sqlite`) but I'm not sure which on is better in terms of performance and easy coding.

The `data` is `text` only and I would be around `2,000 rows` per one query.

Answer (score 1):

For performance, I would suggest going with Sqlite and also, your data will be securely stored in your app.

You can use localStorage for temporary data which is not very important as the localStorage data can be deleted also due to activities of the device's internet browser.

With regards to performance, I suggested sqlite as sqlite does not block the DOM or your view while performing query on it but getting data out of the storage takes few milliseconds more than localStorage, whereas, localStorage completely blocks the DOM when being queried but is a little faster (very minor) than sqlite in fetching the data.

Answer (score 1):

`Localstorage:` its data will not be stored permanently. data stored in localstorage is unreliable. **It is possible for the data to be wiped** due to various reasons. Besides, it has the storage limit of 5 to 10 MB! Though It is better in terms of performance when compared to the below option.

`pouchDB:` If you have installed the [SQLite Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) then pouchDB will automatically use `SQLite`. It's a full database which overcomes both the above limitations by storing data on a specific location in the device's storage. You get unlimited storage.  Apart from that, it can handle complex queries easily whereas localstorage is a simple key-value system. Since you are installing the Cordova Plugin plugin, it makes sure that you have full cross-platform support.

Answer (score 0):

Best option will be to store data into sqlite db because the data you want to store is quite large. The reason is quite simple -CRUD operations require easy coding and the performance is great. Moreover when you plan your architecture you think of all possible expansions whereas local storage can only store limited amount of data.